# How can I fix a problem in my discord bot prefix, when console says I need a keyword-only argument for "intent"?

Tags: python, discord.py

Error message is as the one below:

`Traceback (most recent call last): File "main.py", line 4, in <module> client = commands.Bot(command_prefix='//') TypeError: __init__() missing 1 required keyword-only argument: 'intents'`

I was only trying to start up my discord bot and see if my old code still works and if I can fix anything.